# Pearl theme logo coming up when I Google my business

Tags: theme, custom-theme, logo

My business is using Magento 2.4.5 with Weltpixel Pearl Theme. When I Google the name of my business, the Pearl theme logo comes up instead of our actual logo. Our logo is set as another image under Content < Design < Configuration. How do I fix this?
[image]